# Difference between CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify() and normal Base64 encryption

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt the following hash to base64:

```
6bb984727b8c8c8017207e54b63976dc42ea9d24ad33bd5feeaa66869b650096
```

It's needed to access the API of a website. The website shows an example script in JavaScript using the `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify()` method to encrypt the hash.
The result with this method is

```
a7mEcnuMjIAXIH5Utjl23ELqnSStM71f7qpmhptlAJY=
```

However, every online base64 encryption tool I tried gives me the following result:

```
NmJiOTg0NzI3YjhjOGM4MDE3MjA3ZTU0YjYzOTc2ZGM0MmVhOWQyNGFkMzNiZDVmZWVhYTY2ODY5YjY1MDA5Ng==
```

I need to create the encoded string in C++. I've also already tried 4 different base64encode implementations (OpenSSL and custom codes), but also there I get the above result and the API always answers my string is not correctly encoded.

So where is the difference, and does somebody know a C++ implementation for `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify()`?

Comment: http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64.js ...check the methods for `stringify` and `parse`...the main difference is the WordArray, a CryptoJS's format-independent representation of data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's call

```
a = "6bb984727b8c8c8017207e54b63976dc42ea9d24ad33bd5feeaa66869b650096";
b = "a7mEcnuMjIAXIH5Utjl23ELqnSStM71f7qpmhptlAJY=";
c = "NmJiOTg0NzI3YjhjOGM4MDE3MjA3ZTU0YjYzOTc2ZGM0MmVhOWQyNGFkMzNiZDVmZWVhYTY2ODY5YjY1MDA5Ng==";
```

Both conversions are correct, but depend on what you actually want.

For example the following two equations hold

```
toBase64FromBytes(toBytesFromUtf8(a)) == c
toBase64FromBytes(toBytesFromHex(a)) == b
```

It's a bad idea to trust some kind of online calculator, because they usually don't disclose how they encode stuff, so you will get arbitrary results. If you program it yourself, you get the expected results if you follow the documentation.

I suspect you got `a` by printing a hash or encryption result to the console like this:

```
console.log(result.toString()); // a
```

Most `result` objects in CryptoJS are `WordArray` types. When you call the `toString()` function on such an object, you get a Hex-encoded string of that binary object.

If you print `result.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)` then you get the Base64-encoded string of the binary result.

If you take `a` and directly encode it to Base64, then it is probably assumed that `a` is already a string (e.g. UTF-8 encoded). An online calculator doesn't know that it is Hex-encoded.